# WebDriverException while waiting for visibility

Tags: java, selenium

Since last week I got stuck in a problem that can't resolve it.
I have an ear project containing an EJB project and a WAR project that worked fine before.
When I execute my project first i get the login page, authenticate and get my home page.
But when I want to write in an input, i tell him to wait until the element is visible but it throws a WebDriverEception :

```
Can't send keys to the element com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23 Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (508d2b6115709e937cfa289fdb0a438b)] -> xpath: //div[@class='form-control browse__browse-name-display___2s17-']/following-sibling::input[@type='file']] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

The problem here is that I have an old project with the same files and when I execute it through main class, it works fine but when i want to run it with Junit, i get this exception.
This is my Code :

```
public void sendKeyOnElement(WebElement element, String string) {
    try {
        if (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)) != null) {
            System.out.println("d5allll");
                if (element.getText().equals(""))
                    element.sendKeys(string);
                else {
                    System.out.println("d5al louta");
                    element.clear();
                    element.sendKeys(string);
                }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Can't send keys element not visible ");
        }
    } catch (ElementNotVisibleException v) {
        System.out.println("Element Not Visible");
    } catch (WebDriverException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't send keys to the element " + element.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**After modifying my code it appears to be a Timeout Exception but the problem is that the element exists and returns its tagName and shows that the element is enabled**

```
public boolean waitVisibilityOfElement(WebElement element) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Waiting visibility of element : " + element.getTagName());
        if (element.isEnabled())
            System.out.println("Element " + element.getTagName() + " is enabled");
        else
            System.out.println("Element " + element.getTagName() + " is not enabled");
        fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        return true;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("Time out for visibility");
        return false;
    } catch (ElementNotVisibleException v) {
        System.out.println("Element Not Visible");
        return false;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException u) {
        System.out.println("Element does not exist");
        return false;
    }
}

public void sendKeyOnElement(WebElement element, String string) {
    try {
        if (waitVisibilityOfElement(element)) {
            System.out.println("d5allll");
                if (element.getText().equals(""))
                    element.sendKeys(string);
                else {
                    System.out.println("d5al louta");
                    element.clear();
                    element.sendKeys(string);
                }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Can't send keys element not visible ");
        }
    } catch (ElementNotVisibleException v) {
        System.out.println("Element Not Visible");
    } catch (WebDriverException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't send keys to the element " + element.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I can't show my Html because it is confidential but i can only show the div and input elements :

```
<div class="form-control browse__browse-name-display___2s17-">  </div>
<input type="file" style="display:none">
```

Comment: The error says, that element is not visible. Are you sure that element is visible on the page?

Comment: yes it is when i run it with an old project that i begun with, it works fine with the same locator

Comment: There should be a difference between old and a new one

Comment: Normally if the element is not visible then it should throws a NoSuchElementException or ElementNotVisibleException and not WebDriverException

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov there is no change in class file, it remains the same one but can't make it work in the new project

Comment: Ok, rewrite this part of code from the scratch

Comment: Can you share the HTML for this `//div[@class='form-control browse__browse-name-display___2s17-']/following-sibling::input[@type='file']]`

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov : You see `form-control browse__browse-name-display___2s17-` , this looks quite unstable. May be it's time to change the locator :)

Comment: @cruisepandey thats why I'm suggesting to rewrite this code block from scratch and test it properly

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov :  No need to change the whole test method. May be the locators which are highly unstable and can cause problem in future ?

Comment: @cruisepandey agree

Comment: i modified my code and my post it appeared to be a Timeout Exception but the element exists

Comment: @HamzaTorjmen : Just showing a bit more of HTML would not harm you I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I don't know if it is normal with selenium, but by default the input which its type is file can't be displayed although it is displayed in Web Browser, The method `isEnabled()` returns true and `isDisplayed()` returns false so the wait until will wait, and at the end will throws a Timeout Exception and The most funny thing is even for selenium it is not displayed you can send keys in the input which is not logic.